# Solidity. Return a Sruct that lives inside an array

Tags: solidity, struct, uint256

I am not sure how to return a struct that is inside an array of structs. This is my code:

```
contract StudentsInfoTracker{

    Student[] students;

    struct Student{
        string name;
        address ethAddress;
        uint numberInClass;
        uint[] marks;
    }
    function getStudent(uint) public view returns(string memory name, address ethAddress, uint numberInClass, uint[] memory marks){
        return(students[uint].name, students[uint].ethAddress, students[uint].numberInClass, students[uint].marks);
    }
```

I need to return the student given the uint index. I know I can't return a complete struct but I can try to retrieve its data. Anyway I get this error:

> TypeError: Type type(uint256) is not implicitly convertible to
>   expected type uint256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to name your variable. You only gave it a type. Try this:

```
function getStudent(uint id) ... {
    return (students[id].name, students[id].ethAddress, ...);
}
```